# I need to eliminate the \r\n from within the body of a PHP generated e-mail

Tags: php, phpmailer

Here is my current script:

```
     $toemail = "$appemail";
            $subject = "Bursary Application";

            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
                ."From: Tem <tem@here.ca>\r\n"
                ."Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

            $body =     "<h3>Thank You ".$appfirstname." for applying for the Bursary.</h3>"
                ."<hr />"
                ."<h2>Bursary Application Form</h2>"
                ."<hr />"
                ."<h4>Application Date: ".$appdate."</h4>"
                ."<h4>First Name: ".$appfirstname."</h4>"
                ."<h4>Last Name: ".$applastname."</h4>"
                ."<h4>Birthdate: ".$birthdate."</h4>"
                ."<h4>Mailing Address: ".$appmailingaddress."</h4>"
                ."<h4>City: ".$appcity."</h4>"
                ."<h4>Province: ".$appprovstate."</h4>"
                ."<h4>Postal Code: ".$apppc."</h4>"
                ."<h4>Phone Number: ".$appphone."</h4>"
                ."<h4>Graduation Date: ".$graddate."</h4>"
                ."<h4>Email Address: ".$appemail."</h4>"
                ."<h4>Post Secondary Plans: ".$psplans."</h4>"
                ."<h4>Musical Accomplishments: ".$ma."</h4>"
                ."<h4>Hobbies: ".$hobbies."</h4>"
                ."<h4>Why I enjoy music: ".$why."</h4>"
                ."<h4>How I will use the monetary award: ".$how."</h4>"
                ."<h4>What I would say to the donor: ".$saydonor."</h4>"
                ."<br>"
                ."<br>"
                ."<hr />"
                ."<h4>Thank you for your application.</h4>"
                ."<br>"
                ."<br>"
                ;

            mail($toemail, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

I am getting the data from the form and using text fields for the paragraph answers. I am sending this in the form as test data $psplans. There are carriage returns after each number:

1)Line 1
2)Line 2
3)Line 3

I am getting this in the body of the emailed message:

Post Secondary Plans: 1)Line 1\r\n2)Line 2\r\n3)Line 3

I cannot find a way to eliminate the \r\n. Your help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: You know that those *are* line breaks, right?

Comment: I don't see any `\r\n` in your `$body` ???

Comment: Yes, I know that they are line breaks. I should add that I am using this as well:
$psplans = $conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['psplans']));
I'm using this to clean up the data before inserting it into the database.

If I do not use real_escape_string and I just use:
$psplans = $_POST['psplans'];

With: 
$psplans = preg_replace("/\r\n|\r|\n/",'<br/>',$psplans);

Then I Get the correct format:
1)line break here
2)line break here
3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're outputting html in the email, not text. 
A newline in the source code of html does not appear as a line break in the output.

You can simply use the php function nl2br: http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

to change the line

```
            ."<h4>Post Secondary Plans: ".$psplans."</h4>"
```

to

```
            ."<h4>Post Secondary Plans: ".nl2br($psplans)."</h4>"
```

or use the `<br>` tag yourself instead of the `\n\r` sequence where you insert it already.

Comment: The .nl2br() will NOT work AFTER using real_escape_string. What I learned:
1) Gather Form Data ex: $address=$_POST['address'];
2) Use nl2br before e-mailing."<h4>Address: ".nl2br($address)."</h4>"
3) Use $address = $conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['appfirstname']));
4) Insert into the database.

Comment: real_escape_string: I'd suggest to switch to prepared statements instead and separate code from data. 
I look at data in 3 states: 1: data that is from the client and needs to be validated.   2: data that's valid (and not encoded for a specific use).   3. data in an output encoding. The encoding is quite different for html, email, database, ... use.  Typically I validate data as soon as possible and then never touch the unvalidated data anymore. For output: I just call an output filter routine each time I do output right before I do the output (or right before I prepare the data to be output.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing those characters with html br tag:

```
$psplans = preg_replace("/\r\n|\r|\n/",'<br/>',$psplans);
```

And then use as

```
    ."<h4>Post Secondary Plans: ".$psplans."</h4>"
```